# Cannot login to Reporting Services through SSMS and Reporting Services Configuration manager

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssms, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to connect to reporting services through ssms. I am getting a following error: "A connection to the computer cannot be established. Access is denied"

I have system administrator/system user privileges in report manager. I am also part of sysadmin group in a dev environment that I want to connect. I already opened port 80, 1433, checked all accesses on COM security. Anything else?

By the way, when I try to connect to the same server through reporting services configuration manager, it also doesn't allow me. It says  "A connection to the computer cannot be established".

Details: I am using 2008 R2. It is a corporate server.

Is there something I am missing? Any info will be valued.

Comment: What happens when you try to connect locally?  Also, SSL?  Might need port 433 if it's set up to use SSL.

Comment: I can connect locally. How can I check if it is SSL problem?

Comment: Well, if you can connect locally, you know the problem is related to network access.  Make sure reporting services are set up to accept remote connections, eliminate the firewall as a possible problem (by turning it off temporarily while you troubleshoot), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Had The same issue and resolved by making my user that tries to connect with SSMS remotely to SSRS admin on the server