# Configure SSRS remotely - A connection to the computer cannot be established

Tags: sql-server, configuration, remote-access, ssrs, server-setup

I just installed the newest SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 using this instructions: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

I have a Windows Server with SQL Server Express 2017.

I need to configure the Report Server remotely, but when I try to find the server from the Report Server Configuration Manager it just says that 'A connection to the computer cannot be established' (see image).

[image: Report Server Configuration Manager]

I tested this setup in two separate computers outside the domain (to configure remotely), and it worked fine, but it doesn't work in the Server that is within the domain.

I added my user for permissions with these steps here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-report-server-for-remote-administration?view=sql-server-2017

But it still doesn't connect, any ideas of what's missing?

I had a look at this question too, but couldn't find much help from it:

[Cannot login to Reporting Services through SSMS and Reporting Services Configuration manager](https://serverfault.com/questions/592804/cannot-login-to-reporting-services-through-ssms-and-reporting-services-configura)

**Update**

I have done the following tests:

- Report Server Configuration Manager connects fine if I connect **locally**
- SSMS connect fine **remotely** with either **domain** user or **sa** user
- Based on link above I even did an unsafe test of allowing report server WMI and DCOM permissions to **Everyone** and to **Anonymous logon** the error is still happening if I connect remotely.

  - I also disabled the firewall for the test and the error was still there

Comment: You're sure the service is running after installation, and you're sure you can connect to the host over port 80 (or whatever port is running the SSRS web services)?

Comment: Will you need to be able to connect to port 80 - web services before you configure SSRS? I thought the actual Configuration client needed to do some work setting up the web portal while doing the set up first?

Comment: No, you need to be able to connect via WMI to configure the service. Port 80 (or whatever you have the sites like report manager listen on) is for after. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-report-server-for-remote-administration?view=sql-server-2017 for the WMI config I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, I guessed so. That's the link I've followed, but I even tried in a test VM windows Server, and then connecting to it remotely. I disabled firewall, and added everyone and anonymous to the DCOM and WMI permissions for report server, and nothing worked, I can only connect to it locally. I suspect there's an actual bug from Microsoft side, (or a block to SSRS and SQL server express) :(

Comment: Really? I've done remote connection/setup before, and it's worked for me. I am traveling today. I'll try to spin-up a SSRS VM tonight and recreate your issue.

Comment: With the latest 2017 versions? If you could give it a go, it will be really helpful! :D (make sure you try on windows server / I did hosting on Win10 enterprise which works fine, but not windows server)